# Kotlin serialization: Serializer has not been found for type 'UUID'

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Kotlin Serialization to serialize a custom type which contains a UUID field

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class MyDataClass {
    val field1: String,
    val field2: UUID
}
```

I got the following error and did not know what to do:

```
Serializer has not been found for type 'UUID'. To use context serializer as fallback, explicitly annotate type or property with @Contextual
```

Comment: Happens also on the Java server side.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After following the [Kotlin Custom Serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers) section of the Kotlin Serialization Guide, I realized I had to write an object that looks like this to actually help the UUID serialize/ deserialize, even though `UUID` already implements `java.io.Serializable`:

```kotlin
object UUIDSerializer : KSerializer<UUID> {
        override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("UUID", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): UUID {
                return UUID.fromString(decoder.decodeString())
        }

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: UUID) {
                encoder.encodeString(value.toString())
        }
}

// And also update the original data class:
@Serializable
data class FaceIdentifier(
        val deviceId: String,
        @Serializable(with = UUIDSerializer::class)
        val imageUUID: UUID,
        val faceIndex: Int
)
```

Well it turns out I have to do this for a lot of types: e.g. Rect, Uri, so I will be using Java serialization if possible... Let me know if you know a simpler way.

Comment: Kotlin serialization can't use Java serialization; despite the same name they have very different approach and requirements.

Comment: Well it turns out most of my types are not Java Serializable, just Android `Parcelable`. People have warned against saving this to disk, so I have written the KSerializer implementations for Rect and Uri too. Now I'm fully kotlin. Nice thing is I can read the JSON output file to validate it!

Comment: Works like charm

Comment: Great. But is there really no library that provides such serializer implementations?