# Serializer has not been found for type 'Any'

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization

Im trying to serialize a Json file. But there's many variables with the type 'Any', and the @Serializable annotation is not working with this type.
I've tried to do exactly like the answer in this question:
[Kotlin serialization: Serializer has not been found for type 'UUID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398284/kotlin-serialization-serializer-has-not-been-found-for-type-uuid)
But the problem is that there is no "from string()" function for the type 'Any'.
Is there a solution for this?

Edit:
This is some of the data classes

```
    @Serializable
data class ApiResponse(
    val data:List<ApiResponseItem> = emptyList()
)


@Serializable
data class ApiResponseItem(
    @SerializedName("cards")
    val cards: List<Any>? = null,
    @SerializedName("country_id")
    val country_id: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("country_logo")
    val country_logo: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("country_name")
    val country_name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("fk_stage_key")
    val fk_stage_key: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("goalscorer")
     val goalscorer: List<Any>? = null,
    @SerializedName("league_id")
    val league_id: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("league_logo")
    val league_logo: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("league_name")
    val league_name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("league_year")
    val league_year: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("lineup")
    val lineup: Lineup? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_extra_score")
    val match_awayteam_extra_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_ft_score")
    val match_awayteam_ft_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_halftime_score")
    val match_awayteam_halftime_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_id")
    val match_awayteam_id: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_name")
    val match_awayteam_name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_penalty_score")
    val match_awayteam_penalty_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_score")
    val match_awayteam_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_awayteam_system")
    val match_awayteam_system: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_date")
    val match_date: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_hometeam_extra_score")
    val match_hometeam_extra_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_hometeam_ft_score")
    val match_hometeam_ft_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName(" match_hometeam_halftime_score")
    val match_hometeam_halftime_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_hometeam_id")
    val match_hometeam_id: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_hometeam_name")
    val match_hometeam_name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_hometeam_penalty_score")
    val match_hometeam_penalty_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_hometeam_score")
    val match_hometeam_score: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_hometeam_system")
    val match_hometeam_system: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_id")
    val match_id: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_live")
    val match_live: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_referee")
    val match_referee: String? = null,
    @SerializedName(" match_round")
    val match_round: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_stadium")
    val match_stadium: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("mmatch_status")
    val match_status: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("match_time")
    val match_time: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("stage_name")
    val stage_name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("statistics_1half")
    val statistics_1half: List<Any>? = null,
    @SerializedName("substitutions")
    val substitutions: Substitutions? = null,
    @SerializedName("team_away_badge")
    val team_away_badge: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("team_home_badge")
    val team_home_badge: String? = null
)
```

Comment: please add enough code to your question for us to recreate the problem

Comment: I've added some classes

Comment: not even sure why you're using `@SerializedName("cards")` here, if the name of the variable is the same as what you're getting from the json, i don't think you even need to add it

Comment: @a_local_nobody it might matter when dealing with obfuscation.

Comment: true but no mention of that here

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you can't make a class `Serializable` when it has fields of type `Any`. It's simply not possible because `Any` can quite literally be anything, including classes that are not `Serializable`. Try defining them more specific. I can assume that

```
val cards: List<Any>? = null,
```

is actually maybe

```
val cards: List<Card>? = null,
```

As long as you make sure that the types you put there are `Serializable` it should work