# How to handle Any serialization with kotlinx serialization

Tags: android, json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

I have a JSON response with a parameter which may be of different types depending on the enum value of another parameter.
Example JSON:

```
[
    {
        "type":1,
        "value":"String"
    },
    {
        "type":2,
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "type":3,
        "value": [2, 4]
    }
]
```

How would I go about making a (de)serializer for this? I've seen the docs, but neither the @Polymorphic anotation or the generics seem to work for my usecase.
My desired output would be something like:

```
@Serializable
abstract class MyData(open val type: Int, open val value: Any)
@Serializable
data class StringData(override val type: Int, override val value: String): MyData(type, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Will provide more detail if not working.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Serializable
data class MyData(val type: Int, val value: Any)

val data = Json.decodeFromString<List<MyData>>("""[
    {
        "type":1,
        "value":"String"
    },
    {
        "type":2,
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "type":3,
        "value": [2, 4]
    }
]""")

println(data)
```

Comment: This throws the following error: Serializer has not been found for type 'Any'.
Also, it doesn't allow me to map to the correct class based on the enum, which I would prefer to do rather than unpacking the any later on in the code :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289849/7874746